# Negative or positive newtons

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, coordinate-systems, vectors, conventions

Do we write

A car needs 6000N of force to be stopped

or

A car needs -6000N of force to be stopped

Answer (score 3):

In the general approach, force is a vector, so it has magnitude and direction.
When you state what is the force that the car needs in order to stop you have to state both the magnitude and direction of that force. **In this approach the answer will be 6000N (this is magnitude so by definition it's positive) in the opposite direction of the velocity of the car**

Other approach is to use coordinates in order to represent the physical sizes of the system.
In this case the sign of the answer will depend on the direction of your axis (assuming that we have only one dimension and one axis). **If the force is in the same direction of your axis then the answer will be 6000N. If the force is in the opposite direction from your axis then the answer will be -6000N.**

Note that the second approach (using coordinates) works well only if your problem is one dimensional. In the n-dimensional case you will have to use n numbers in order to represent each component of the force vector.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is said generally like this:

A car needs a 6000N force to be stopped.

But the scenario changes when we take account of the vectors.
It all depends which direction you are taking as positive direction.
If you take the positive direction to be along the motion of the car, then we must say that:

The car needs a -6000N force to be stopped.

More plainly, the (-) sign only denotes the direction of force.